How to process ajax callback value using switch?
I am making an Ajax call in my code and want to process the result using a switch statement. The switch statement or even an if statement is just not working in the callback. A console.log is showing me the right value coming back from the server.
      $.ajax({type: "POST",
      url: "term_updt.php",
      data: {.....},
      success:function(result) 
        { 
            var res = result;
            if(res == 0)
            {
                $('.overlay').show();
                $('.redOk').center();
                $('.redOk').show();
                $(".redOk").delay(800).fadeOut(300);
                window.location = "redemption.php";
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(res);
                switch(res)
                {
                    case('invalid_date'):
                    {
                        $('.redErr').text('Please enter a valid date');
                        $('#end_end_date').focus();
                        break;
                    }
                    case('invalid_nav'):
                    {
                        $('.redErr').text('Please enter a valid NAV');
                        $('#end_end_nav').focus();
                        break;
                    }
                    case('invalid_qty'):
                    {
                        $('.redErr').text('Please enter a valid Quantity');
                        $('#end_qty').focus();
                        break;
                    }
                    case('1'):
                    {
                        $('.redErr').text('A critical error occured');
                        break;
                    }
                }
                $('.redErr').show();
            }  

The value returned is invalid_qty which should get caught by the switch statement but it is not. Where am I going wrong?


Trim the string, there might be white spaces in the response.

Debug to determine the exact value of res - console.log will not show whitespace.  You could also do similar to console.log("[" + res + "]") as it appears to be meant to be a string
